# webconfig not auto populating on consuming WCF

Tags: wcf

I'm sorry if it's basic question, but I'm newbie and my company assigned me task to consume WCF service form one of our client. The client have provided me with their hosted WCF service URL. Everything was wonderful, Microsoft have done wonderful job of keeping things simple, i was confident that i can achieve it. But when i try to add service reference in my project, my web config file is not populated, and I'm not able to get endpoint binding and other information which I believe supposed to be populated automatically.

[The screenshot of my referenced WEBServcie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXOwQ.png)-----
[This is how im calling service in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXijl.png)-------
[my complete webconfig,u can see it's not auto populated by end points/binding information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IYNU.png)
-------[and Finaly the exception I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms52V.png)

Comment: Better post your code and web.config here to let us know what is happening

Comment: Hey Tony... i've added screenshot now as edit post

Comment: Please try http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/shinuraj587/testing-wcf-service-using-test-client-wcftestclient-exe/ for testing your WCF

Comment: Hey @TonyDong.. I've tried it, when i add it's displaying as "successful",  but not methods are available to invoke, moreover after some googling i've tried svcutil.exe as well which results in returning 404  bad request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for help, apparently I was missing complete information from the client, make sure you get all the headers you need to add in httprequest. THe client forgot to provide me with applicationid which one suppose to add in request header.

Answer (score 1):

if you have multiple solutions in you project and if you are adding the service reference in other than your start up project. Please check that particular project App.config file.

If you already verified in that way, even though it is not adding means it might be issue with service creation.

Comment: ok let me get back from the dev team, will post the reason once I'll got it. Thanks